# How to powershell script the IIS warm-up for asp.net 4.0?

Tags: iis, powershell

Can anybody please tell me how to powershell script the IIS to use the asp.net 4.0 warm-up mechanism?

I've created this powershell script, but it doesn't seem to write anything into the applicationHost.config file:
( trying to implement step 3 from here, but using Powershell: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/01/31/asp-net-4-0-how-to-use-application-warm-up-class.aspx )

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$SiteName="Default Web Site"
$ApplicationName=“WebOne“

Add-WebConfiguration "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='WebOne']" -Value @{serviceAutoStartEnabled="true";serviceAutoStartProvider="PreWarmMyCache"} -PSPath IIS:\Sites\$SiteName\$ApplicationName -Location $SiteName/$ApplicationName
```

I'm trying to add these two(2) properties `( serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" and serviceAutoStartProvider="PreWarmMyCache"):`

e.g.:

```
<application path="/" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" serviceAutoStartProvider="PreWarmMyCache" />:
```

To my current Application Path:

```
<sites>
     <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
                <application path="/WebOne" applicationPool="ASP.NET v4.0">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\NetProjects\WebOne" />
                </application>         
     </site>
</sites>
```

I will also need to powershell script this:
( step 4 from here, but using Powershell: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/01/31/asp-net-4-0-how-to-use-application-warm-up-class.aspx )

```
<serviceAutoStartProviders>
     <add name="PreWarmMyCache" type="PreWarmCache, MyAssembly" />
</serviceAutoStartProviders>
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.-

I've already powershell scripted this stuff below which is also needed, but I need the stuff above ( serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" and serviceAutoStartProvider="PreWarmMyCache" ), which I mentioned.-

```
#Load IIS Modules
Import-Module WebAdministration   

if (Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\SosSWarmUpWorkerProcess)
{
    #Let's delete the entry if it's already there ( while deploying between versions )
    Remove-Item IIS:\AppPools\SosSWarmUpWorkerProcess -Force -Recurse
}

$myNewPool = New-Item IIS:\AppPools\SosSWarmUpWorkerProcess  
$myNewPool.managedRuntimeVersion = "4.0"
$myNewPool.startMode="AlwaysRunning"

$myNewPool | Set-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a parameter to New-Item or New-WebApplication that allows you to set the AutoStart for the new application. But, you can set the property after creating the app:

```
$vdirPath = Join-Path "IIS:\Sites" (Join-Path $iisSite $virtualDirectoryName)
New-Item $vdirPath -physicalPath $webSitePath -type Application 
Set-ItemProperty $vdirPath -name serviceAutoStartEnabled -value "true"
Set-ItemProperty $vdirPath -name serviceAutoStartProvider -value "PreWarmMyCache"
```